# Batch export rasters as rendered images

Tags: qgis, raster, pyqgis

I want to export a lot of raster layers as rendered images. After looking around, I got to this code:

```
myDir = 'e:/Data/'
layers = [layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]
pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
for layer in layers:
   extent = layer.extent()
   width, height = layer.width(), layer.height()
   renderer = layer.renderer()
   provider=layer.dataProvider()
   crs = layer.crs().toWkt() 
   pipe.set(provider.clone())
   pipe.set(renderer.clone())
   file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(myDir + layer.name() + ".tif")
   file_writer.writeRaster(pipe,
                           width,
                           height,
                           extent,
                           layer.crs())
```

But when I run it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.12\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QgsVectorLayer' object has no attribute 'width'
```

I'm using QGIS 3.12.2.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To help you understand the cause of the error, in the block of code you are iterating through all the layers loaded in the current project. In each iteration, you are calling methods such as `width()` and `height()` on the object referenced in the `layer` identifier. The object stored in this reference changes dynamically on each iteration of the for loop. I am guessing you have at least one vector layer loaded in your project as well as raster layers. Since `QgsVectorLayer` objects do not have the `width()` or `height()` methods, when the for loop hits a vector layer the error you received is raised.

This can be avoided by adding a conditional to the list comprehension so that only `QgsRasterLayer` objects are collected. You could use something like:

```
if isinstance(layer, QgsRasterLayer)
```

However, this would also include WMS layers etc. which may not be what you want. I used:

```
if layer.dataProvider().name() == 'gdal'
```

The code below is working for me (tested in 3.14.15). I have made a few other small changes. Since 3.8 you should also pass a `QgsCoordinateTransformContext()` argument to the `writeRaster()` method.

See: https://qgis.org/api/classQgsRasterFileWriter.html#a16e7914edef28fd41db83f599224f560

Also, I recommend using `os.path.join()` for constructing file path strings.

```
import os

myDir = 'e:/Data'
project = QgsProject().instance()
layers = [layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()
            if layer.dataProvider().name() == 'gdal']
pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
for layer in layers:
    pipe.set(layer.dataProvider().clone())
    pipe.set(layer.renderer().clone())
    output_path = os.path.join(myDir, '{}.tif'.format(layer.name()))
    file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(output_path)
    file_writer.Mode=1
    file_writer.writeRaster(pipe,
                           layer.width(),
                           layer.height(),
                           layer.extent(),
                           layer.crs(),
                           project.transformContext())
```