# Merge delimited text file with the raster files in QGIS to download

Tags: qgis, python

In this code, each Raster file is downloaded correctly using Python from QGIS.
But what I expect is, to merge a delimited text layer onto each raster layer and download it.

```py
import os

myDir = 'D:\\UCC\\Project\\Full_DataWCT\\'  
project = QgsProject().instance()  
layers = [layer for layer in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values() if layer.dataProvider().name() == 'gdal']  
pipe = QgsRasterPipe()
                                                                                  
for layer in layers:  
                                  
        pipe.set(layer.dataProvider().clone())  
        pipe.set(layer.renderer().clone())  
        output_path = os.path.join(myDir, '{}.png'.format(layer.name()))  
        file_writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(output_path)  
        file_writer.writeRaster(pipe, layer.width(), layer.height(), layer.extent(), layer.crs(), project.transformContext())
```

Code reference - [Batch export rasters as rendered images](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/371586/batch-export-rasters-as-rendered-images)

Comment: Please let me know if my question isn't clear or if I missed something that might be beneficial?

Comment: The code I copied is provided by you, Maybe you can help @ben-w